# Cannot read file with nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, fs

I use the following code to read a file from my desktop. When I run the server and use some request I don't see anything in the debugger.

What am I missing here?

```
fs = require('fs');   
fs.readFile('‪C:\Users\i123\Desktop\test.txt', 'utf8', function (err,data) {
     if (err) {
         return console.log(err);
     }
     console.log(data);
     res.send(data);
});
```

Comment: *"I dont see nothing in the debugger"* Which debugger are you talking about? If you don't see any output in the terminal (where you started your app), it means the code is not executed at all (but there is too little information to even have an idea why)

Comment: And are you actually invoking that code when you "use some request"?

Comment: are 'my desktop' and 'the server' on the same machine?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's hard to know all the things that might be wrong here since you only show a small piece of your code, but one thing that is wrong is the filename string.  The `\` character in Javascript is an escape mechanism so that the string `'‪C:\Users\i123\Desktop\test.txt'` is not what you want it to be.  If you really need backslashes in the string for a Windows filename, then you would need to use this:

```
'‪C:\\Users\\i123\\Desktop\\test.txt'
```

---

Other things I notice about your code:

1. Returning a value from the `readFile()` callback does nothing.  It just returns a value back into the bowels of the async file I/O which does nothing.
2. When you get a file error, you aren't doing anything with the `res` which presumably means this route isn't doing anything and the browser will just be left waiting.